# Adding .pdf to published application

Tags: c#, pdf

I've been building an application using Windows Forms and have written a user manual for employees to navigate it. I have the manual saved as a .pdf, and I've included a button on the menu screen to open the file. I have the option to save the file on the company server but I would rather package the file in the ClickOnce installation so that it can be used off-server if the need arises. I'm very new to C# and haven't been able to find a similar question yet.

Thank you in advance for your help.

Answer (score 0):

If you include the file in the application's Visual Studio project, you can then go to the properties for the file and change the option `Copy to Output Directory` from `Do not copy` to either `Copy always` or `Copy if newer`.

Next time you compile the file will then be included in the project output and copied to the bin folder with the rest of the application, which you can package up as normal.